# I am trying to split a String but I want to keep the delimiter

Tags: javascript

I have the following string `<=10 & <20` and I want to split this string so it gives the following results `('<=' '10' '<' '20')` the & is irrelevant because I deal with that in a different area of my code! thanks

Comment: the results are then put into an array incase your wondering why i'm trying to do this

Comment: regex is the solution

Comment: the & is irrelevant, I just want to split the string but be able to keep my delimiter

Comment: how are you splitting it now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex. Possible example for your question:

```
"<=10 & <20".match(/(([<=>]+)|(\d+))/g)
```

that returns exactly what you need:

```
["<=", "10", "<", "20"]
```

Of course final regexp depends from what are possible operators your string could have

if you also need support for negative values you can change expression to:

```
"<=10 & <-20".match(/(([<=>]+)|(-?\d+))/g)
```

and as result:

```
["<=", "10", "<", "-20"]
```

Comment: Beware that this will happily match `<=>>=<` as a single operator...

Comment: this is perfect :) the operators where '<=' '<' '>=' '>' and this handles them all

Comment: @SmokeyPHP You're right. Thank you. As I said the final regexp will actually depend from final requirement. Because I don't know all possible values that the string might have so I just showed the main idea and concrete solution for the original question.

Comment: what if i had <=-10 & <-20 and wanted it to return '<=' '-10' '<=' '-20' (can be either positive or negative?

Comment: @MarkDuffy yes it is possible with small changes

Comment: @MarkDuffy I changed my answer and added example with negative numbers support

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you wan't to tokenize a string like a compiler do. If you already took computer science classes you should have knowledge of [Lexical Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis). In short, you need a State Machine to tokenize the string in a flexible way. I don't see another way of solving this requirement.

Just a glimpse of the algorithm:

```
var tokens = new Array();
var inputStr ...;

... a lot of state variables

var currentState = LexicalAnalysisStates.START;

for (var i = 0; i < inputStr.length; i++) { 
  var nextChar = input.charAt(i);
  switch (currentState) {
  case LexicalAnalysisStates.START: ...; // process nextChar considering START state
  case LexicalAnalysisStates.DIGIT: ...; // process nextChar considering DIGIT state
  case LexicalAnalysisStates.EQUAL: ...; // process nextChar considering EQUAL state
  }
}

... here you should have your token collection populated
```

Hint: start by drawing sketches of the final state machine, like [this one](http://www.viva64.com/media/images/content/a/Static_analyzer_development/image6.png)

EDIT: updated the code to Javascript syntax after Artem's comment.

Comment: Is this answer really relevant/required?

Comment: Why not? A simple regexp won't help the OP if my assumptions around his requirements are valid and her splitting needs become a lot more complex...

Comment: @samuelgrigolato While your answer has value for Java, but the question tagged as "javascript"

Comment: Thank you @Artem, I updated my answer, as the concept remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
var str;

str = '<=10';
str.match(/([^0-9]+)([0-9]+)/); // ["<=10", "<=", "10"]

str = '<20';
str.match(/([^0-9]+)([0-9]+)/); // ["<20", "<", "20"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're after (ensures proper syntax of `>=` `<=` `>` `<`):

```
"<=10 & <20".match(/(<|>)=?|(\d+)/g);//["<=", "10", "<", "20"]
```